# Need to create a custom blank page in drupal

Tags: php, drupal

I've installed Drupal to have a basic user registration layer. Now I need to code some PHP code in a blank page, how I can achieve this in Drupal? I need to know where I must put my PHP code.

Thanks a lot

Edit.

Basically I need Drupal only for user authorization. After a user logged into the system I want to show him a table with some data. This table was managed with JQuery.

Comment: That depends you could add a file into a custom theme or module, but you will need to know what you're doing. The page not just going to magically work for you. You will need to supply some more information about what you're trying to do here.

Comment: You will still need to know drupal could also be a good idea to tag your question with the version you're using and I think you should move this question to drupal.stackexchange.com

Comment: I'm going to make the assumption that if you want to show them a table of data and that you want to do so with custom PHP that the information isn't coming directly from Drupals database? Unless your platform never has reason to expand or increase, why don't you incorporate the data into drupal content? Then you can use the views module to do any number of operations on it

Comment: thanks Andrew Morris this is a good point!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for what you want to do I think it's not necessary a custom module, but if so, it's not so hard to do, but you can allways use some existing drupal modules mixed together to do what you want.

You will need:
[Display Suite](https://drupal.org/project/DS) and
[Login Redirect module](https://drupal.org/project/login_redirect)

> Basically I need Drupal only for user authorization. After a user
>   logged into the system I want to show him a table with some data.

For this purpose you can use [Login Redirect module](https://drupal.org/project/login_redirect) to redirect user to any page you want.

> Now I need to code some PHP code in a blank page, how I can achieve
>   this in Drupal? I need to know where I must put my PHP code.

For this you can use [Display Suite](https://drupal.org/project/DS). Display suite or simply DS comes with a new a new Text Format: **"Display Suite code"**. This text format allow you to add some custom code to your pages (javascript,php,etc)

Answer (score 2):

you should learn to develop Drupal modules
with hook_menu you can make page
and with hook_form_alter you can edit registration form

but in drupal 7 you can manage registration fields
and also with [rules](https://drupal.org/project/rules) and [views](https://drupal.org/project/views) modules, you can manage registration and user list without PHP coding

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create a module in order to add php code to drupal. Try this to understand better what u need to do https://drupal.org/node/1074360